# How to add terms to model to extract entities from text

Tags: elasticsearch, stanford-nlp, opennlp, elasticsearch-plugin

We want to add new terms and synonyms to Stanford NER engine and have engine extract new terms in a document. Also wondering if elastic search couldn't be of help.

Use case - making bread and I want to add terms to the engine like white flour, wheat flour, rice flour. All documents that are enriched should have - white flour, wheat flour, rice flour - highlighted and classified as a "bread making" thing vs org/person/location.

Not sure if its possible or how to do add the terms to the model reading the docs online.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you look at the RegexNER.  It can be run as one of the annotators with the pipeline along with the standard NER.

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner/

Please let me know if you need any more help!